# redirect to url entered in text box

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I want it to redirect to the url entered in the text box when "unblock" is clicked.

...........................................................................

```
<center>
</font>
  <input size="40" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" name="getId" type="text" id="getId" style="background-color: black;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor:;" placeholder="Enter website URL here" />

<button style="background-color: black;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;"id="btnUnblock" onclick="createLink()">Unblock</button>


</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createLink()
{
    var value_input = document.getElementById('getId').value;

    window.location.href = value_input;
}
```